# How do you concatenate with a list?

Tags: python, concatenation

I'm relatively new to python and I'm trying to concatenate with lists. This is my best attempt but obviously it doesn't work. Anyone know a way to do this? Thanks

```
present = ["Jake", "Jimmy", "Karen"]
print("The people present are " + present)
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want to print out the people's names smooshed together? Comma separated? Do you literally want the entire list, brackets and all, printed?

Comment: `print("The people present are " + str(present))`  ?

Comment: Thanks atline, thats all I wanted it to do :D

Comment: You can also pass multiple args to `print`, e.g. `print("The people present are", present)`.  `print` will automatically convert each individual argument to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert the list into a string before you can do the string concatenation with the `+` operator. You can use the `str.join()` method to accomplish this.

```
present = ["Jake", "Jimmy", "Karen"]
print("The people present are " + ", ".join(present))
```

This is going to create a string with each item in the list and use the string `', '` as a separator between each element.

Check out the w3 schools examples here https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp

Or the official python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```py
>>> some_list = ['Jack', 'Jill', 'Hill']
>>> print("The story centrally features the characters: " + ", ".join(some_list))
The story centrally features the characters: Jack, Jill, Hill
```